# An error is occur when we use navigation to move other page

Tags: windows-phone-7

```
using System;
using System.Windows;
using System.Windows.Controls;
using System.Windows.Navigation;

namespace WindowsPhoneApplication7
{
    public partial class Listbox : UserControl
    {
        public Listbox()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        private void listbox(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
        {
            this.NavigationService.Navigate(new Uri("/home.xaml", UriKind.Relative));
        }
    }
}
```

An error is occur .......
does not contain a definition for 'NavigationService' and no extension method 'NavigationService' accepting a first argument of type ' could be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)

Answer (score 1):

`NavigationService` is a property on the `PhoneApplicationPage` class.  You are not deriving from that class, you are deriving from `UserControl`.

You need to get the parent phone page the user control is on and get the NavigationService reference from there.

Your compiler error is because it cannot locate a definition for `NavigationService` on the `Listbox` class you have made.

Answer (score 0):

What Adam said is correct. But a easy solution is to define following static utility methods in App.xaml.cs

```
public static PhoneApplicationFrame CurrentRootVisual
{
    get
    {
        return (App.Current.RootVisual as PhoneApplicationFrame);
    }
}

public static bool Navigate(Uri source)
{
    if (CurrentRootVisual != null)
        return CurrentRootVisual.Navigate(source);

    return false;
}

public static void GoBack()
{
    if (CurrentRootVisual != null)
        CurrentRootVisual.GoBack();
}
```

Then you can just do:

```
App.Navigate(yourNavigateUri)
```

or
    App.GoBack()

From anywhere you like!

Comment: This is a great technique, but alas! It doesn't work :( I'm still getting the same error myself.

Answer (score 0):

```
Dispatcher.BeginInvoke(() =>
    NavigationService.Navigate(new Uri("/home.xaml", UriKind.Relative)));
```